# Orange sauce for goose

Tags: sauce, chinese-cuisine, oranges, goose

I've been to this wonderful Chinese place where they served goose in orange sauce/gravy.
I've been looking for a recipe for it all over the Internet, but everything I found looked pretty far from it.

The main difference was that they served the goose with unpeeled orange quarters (more like 8th's of oranges, unpeeled) on it, along with the sauce, which was what made the flavor so special. Sometimes there were even seeds on it; that's how raw it was (although it was hot and steamy).

I don't really care about what to do with the goose, I just want to know how to make that sauce.

This is what I'm looking for; you can see that the oranges themselves:

[image: goose in orange sauce]

Comment: It's not orange garnish, the whole thing about the dish was that the orange pieces (including the peel and everything) were the best part.

Comment: You say it was "raw" because there were seeds. Do you mean that the orange pieces were uncooked? (Seems like you'd get a lot of awesome mingled flavors if they *were* cooked at least a bit, so that the sauce took on the flavor from the orange peel, and the oranges took on the flavor of the sauce including drippings from the goose.)

Comment: by raw I mean that the orange pieces didn't seem like they had more attention rather then being cut and steamed just like that, they maintained their flavor, and were very hot. also they were more chewy, but above all, the flavors were that of an orange and of roast goose. And as I've said, I'm less interested about the goose more than I am about the oranges themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make it with a duck demi-glace or some simmered down duck stock, juice from a bitter orange, and perhaps a bit of Grand Marnier or other orange liquer. If you're looking for a Chinese influence, you could simmer it with a star anise or two.

There are any number of duck a l'orange recipes online (duck and goose are fairly similar flavour wise) if you need inspiration.

Comment: star anise is a definite yes in this context

Answer (score 0):

A simple orange glaze can be created by warming the contents of a can of frozen concentrated OJ in a small pot and let that simmer for a while. You then pour that over your goose (or try it with ham, turkey or chicken). You can add other flavors (lemon, mint, amaretto) as it simmers to your liking and imagination.

If you want to garnish with real oranges, you can slice and add them, but the flavor really comes from the concentrate. I recommend using a 'major brand' rather than your local store brand/generic as the major brands have better quality control for the sweetness of their juice.

Answer (score 0):

For the Orange glaze, I would use the concentrated orange juice. To balance the sweetness, the classic way is to use a *gastrique*, which is melted sugar dissolved in vinegar. For the oranges, I think canned mandarin oranges would work well, just leave them in the sauce long enough to heat through.

Also note that a lot of asian style glazes are thickened with cornstarch, so the sauce is clear.